# Express body-parser timeout when white space in POST

Tags: node.js, express, body-parser

In our server.js we use bodyparser in order to read HTTP POST data and access `req.body`:

```
app.use(bodyParser.json());
app.use(bodyParser.urlencoded({ extended: true }));
```

When we POST following data: `{"4":"2"}`, request goes through and we get a 404, fine. When we POST `{"4": "2"}` (notice the white space), the request just times out.

When we disable `app.use(bodyparser.json())`, the request goes through again when posting with white space. What are we doing wrong?

Here is a dumbed down server example, requests are made using Postman.

```
import 'zone.js/dist/zone-node';
import 'reflect-metadata';

import * as express from 'express';
import * as bodyParser from 'body-parser';
import * as request from 'request';
import * as url from 'url';

const app = express();
// app.use(bodyParser.json());

app.post('/code/*', (req: express.Request, res: express.Response, next: express.NextFunction) => {
  const parsedUrl = url.parse('http://testdev.com');
  const options: any = {
    url: url.format({
      protocol: req.protocol,
      host: req.get('host'),
      pathname: req.originalUrl
    }),
    json: req.body,
    headers: {
      ...req.headers,
      'host': parsedUrl.host,
      'hostname': parsedUrl.hostname
    }
  };
  request.post(options).pipe(res);
});

app.listen(5000, () => { });
```

Comment: Please fully explain.

Comment: Can you provide HAR (HTTP Archive)?

Comment: Can you show how you are sending the data to your API? Are you doing it using URL or something like an AJAX call?